# Running Gulp and I get this error: File to import not found or unreadable: util/util

Tags: gulp, zurb-foundation, bower, gulp-sass, zurb-foundation-6

So I am pretty new at using gulp and I am having an issue getting my foundation 6 to compile correctly.

I keep getting this error:

**File to import not found or unreadable: util/util**

I think it might be some sort of path issue but I cant seem to figure it out.

This is my gulpfile.js

```
// Include gulp
var gulp = require('gulp');

// Include Our Plugins
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

// Lint Task
gulp.task('lint', function() {
    return gulp.src('js/*.js')
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'));
});

// Compile Our Sass
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('assets/scss/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css'));
});

// Concatenate & Minify JS
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src('js/*.js')
        .pipe(concat('all.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/js'))
        .pipe(rename('all.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/js'));
});

// Watch Files For Changes
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('assets/js/*.js', ['lint', 'scripts']);
    gulp.watch('assets/scss/*.scss', ['sass']);
});

// Default Task
gulp.task('default', ['lint', 'sass', 'scripts', 'watch']);
```

Main SCSS File.

```
@charset 'utf-8';

@import 'settings';
@import 'foundation';
@import 'motion-ui';

@include foundation-global-styles;
@include foundation-grid;
// @include foundation-flex-grid;
@include foundation-typography;
@include foundation-button;
@include foundation-forms;
// @include foundation-range-input;
@include foundation-accordion;
@include foundation-accordion-menu;
@include foundation-badge;
@include foundation-breadcrumbs;
@include foundation-button-group;
@include foundation-callout;
@include foundation-close-button;
@include foundation-menu;
@include foundation-menu-icon;
@include foundation-drilldown-menu;
@include foundation-dropdown;
@include foundation-dropdown-menu;
@include foundation-flex-video;
@include foundation-label;
@include foundation-media-object;
@include foundation-off-canvas;
@include foundation-orbit;
@include foundation-pagination;
@include foundation-progress-bar;
// @include foundation-progress-element;
// @include foundation-meter-element;
@include foundation-slider;
@include foundation-sticky;
@include foundation-reveal;
@include foundation-switch;
@include foundation-table;
@include foundation-tabs;
@include foundation-thumbnail;
@include foundation-title-bar;
@include foundation-tooltip;
@include foundation-top-bar;
@include foundation-visibility-classes;
@include foundation-float-classes;
// @include foundation-flex-classes;

@include motion-ui-transitions;
@include motion-ui-animations;

// NOUVEAU mixins, including image-url() fix
@import "nv-mixins";

// Load NOUVEAU compatibility styles
@import "nv-wordpress";

// Color
$brand-orange: #ff9900;
$brand-hove-blue: #0066cc;
$brand-blue: #181826;
$brand-dark-blue: #1b1b25;
$brand-dark-blue2: #181826;
$brand-light-grey: rgba(206, 206, 208, 0.5);
$brand-orange-rgba: rgba(255, 153, 0, 0.5);
$brand-blue-rgba: rgba(0, 102, 204, 0.5);

@import 'parts/general';
@import 'parts/header';
@import 'pages/home';
@import 'pages/insurance';
@import 'pages/news';
@import 'pages/why-us';
@import 'pages/contact';
@import 'parts/footer';
```

Here is screen shot of my folder structure.

http://puu.sh/nTIZ0/01f8065605.png

Line where the error is happening

http://puu.sh/nTJ1x/42301e8ed1.png

The Console Error

http://puu.sh/nTJaL/6a7f66fc31.png

Comment: What does the parent SCSS file look like where you reference util/_util.scss?

Comment: Edited the main post with the main scss file.

Comment: main.scss doesn't have an @import for util/util though. What file contains that import?

Comment: The _settings.scss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var sassOptions = {
    errLogToConsole: true,
    outputStyle: 'expanded',
    includePaths: 'bower_components/foundation-sites/scss'
};
// Compile Our Sass
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('assets/scss/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass(sassOptions))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css'));
});
```

Take a look at the Zurb template - I learned a lot from copying bits and pieces from it.

But I believe that the main problem you are facing is that you haven't told your build script where to look for Foundation.

Comment: This is actually your sass task - I did not notice that you named it differently. What you need to do is pass includePaths to Sass via the sassOptions argument. :)

Comment: This worked thanks! Getting another error now for Motion-UI, I suppose I just add another includePaths for that as well?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/jacmoe/yii2-app-basic-zurbified/blob/master/Gulpfile.js

Comment: My version has not been updated to Zurb 6.2 yet ( it is 6.1 ) The Babel stuff takes some changing..

Answer (score 0):

Try using a glob for your sass task so it will check sub-folders.

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
return gulp.src('assets/scss/**/*.scss') // This Line
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css'));
});
```

Comment: Is your parent css file that imports util/_util.scss in the /scss folder?

Comment: Yes it is in the scss folder. its called app.scss http://puu.sh/nTIZ0/01f8065605.png

Comment: Maybe I don't understand how bower works. Doesn't app.scss need an import like `../../bower_components/foundation_sites/scss/util/_util.scss`? There is no /util directory in the /wozencraft directory

Comment: Thats exactly where I am stuck too. I have tried moving the bower_components into the wozencraft directory but that isn't working either.